# Is the second "are" required in "Here are the ideas I thought are worth spreading"?

Tags: grammar

1. Here are the ideas I thought *are* worth spreading.
2. Here are the ideas I thought worth spreading.

Which one is correct?

Comment: I don't see any reason for downvoting this question unless it's been asked before.

Comment: Upvote because it's a reasonable question.

Comment: Should be "I thought were worth spreading" (past tense), or "I think are worth spreading" (present), IMO.

Answer (score 2):

> - #2 Seems better to me because the verb **are** is unnecessary, so #1 is just a bit clunky.

Below, I put (**that**) in parentheses because so many native speakers believe that it's almost always optional. I like to use it because it makes the sentence clearer in most cases. Just a style choice.

> - #1 would be better as #2 or as *Here are the ideas (**that**) I thought **were** worth spreading*.

I put **are** into the past tense -- **were** -- because **thought** is in the past tense. Another style choice. It's more consistent to me, but others will disagree. They're both grammatically correct and fine in context. **Thought** can be changed to **think** without changing the meaning of the sentence.

> - *Here are the ideas (**that**) I think **are** worth spreading*.

This seems best to me because there's no ambiguity about whether I still think they are worth spreading. Using **thought** suggests that I thought this before but may not think it now. Using **were** suggests that it may be too late to spread these ideas now, or that I'm talking about "ancient" history (iPad 1, OS2, the French Revolution, etc.).

Comment: Upvote because it's a good answer. Why was it even downvoted?